# Identifying semantic errors

Tags: python, antlr4, semantics

```
import printf, printf;
void foo(int x, int y) {
 return 0;
}
int a = food(1, -2.0, 5);
```

I need to write a solution to identify all semantic errors that are in the above code. I have a supplied compiler for it.

What is the best way of going about this.

Comment: How would a parser find semantic errors? It can only detect syntactic errors. Can you give us an example for a semantic error you would like to be detected in this example?

Answer (score 2):

ANTLR is about syntax (not particularly about semantics).  You can have semantic predicates, but the intention there is to guide the interpretation of the syntax if there would otherwise be ambiguities (there can be other reasons).

It is *possible* to handle some semantic processing in actions, but this can quickly lead to an ANTLR grammar where it’s hard to find the grammar in all the noise of the actions.  I view this as something of an anti-pattern (particularly in hand crafting grammars).

Code your syntax in the grammar, use the resulting code to produce a ParseTree.  You can then use either Listeners or Visitors to write your own code to do any semantic validation.  This separation of concerns will also help keep the code base easier to manage.

It’s a bit much to go into listeners and visitors in depth in a SO answer, but there is plenty written about using them.

So in your example, ANTLR could produce a perfectly valid ParseTree for the `foo` function, and a parse tree from it.  In a listener for the function context, you could detect that the function *says* it’s return type is `void` and then check the body of the function (in the parse tree) to see if it contains any `return statements.  These would be syntactically “correct” but semantically invalid, so you’d identify that as an error.

In short, ANTLR is great at giving you a data structure that accurately represents the only way to interpret the input stream.  And it provides utility functionality with Listeners and Visitors to make it pretty simple to analyze that parse tree in search of semantic issues (or even use a visitor to produce an interpreter to execute the code, if you’d like).